# Trouble getting accurate calculation with UDF

Tags: sql-server

I am a novice lost in translation! I am trying to perform calculation using a User Define Function and a CustomerID as the Input Parameter.
The calculation seem to work if I am performing calculating a single row.

However, because a single customer can make many support calls, a customer can have multiple row of charges.

If I try to calculate using CustomerID 1, the amount I get is not accurate. I have turned this code upside down and can't understand how to get this going.

Here is a link to the snap shop of the table: I am new and cannot attached images.
[See table Snapshot to illustrated values and rows](http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6215/6341749122_ecbba224c8_b.jpg)

And here is the function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.CalulateTotal (@CustomerId INT) 
RETURNS MONEY 
AS 
BEGIN
DECLARE @GetTotalCost MONEY         
SELECT  @GetTotalCost = ISNULL((SUM(SupportHours) * MAX(CostPerHour)),0) + ISNULL((SUM(MilesTraveled) * MAX(CostPer_Mile)),0)
+ ISNULL((SUM(Supplies) + MAX(Misc)),0)
FROM tblSupportCharges                 
WHERE CustomerId = @CustomerId
GROUP BY CustomerId

RETURN @GetTotalCost
END

Select dbo.CalulateTotal(1)
```

The result for calculating CustomerId 1 SHOULD BE 13 not 15.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

`15` seems correct:

```
SELECT  @GetTotalCost = ISNULL((SUM(SupportHours) * MAX(CostPerHour)),0)
                      + ISNULL((SUM(MilesTraveled) * MAX(CostPer_Mile)),0)
                      + ISNULL((SUM(Supplies) + MAX(Misc)),0)


              ---     =       SUM(5, 2)           * MAX(2, 1)  
              ---     +       SUM(1, NULL)        * MAX(1, NULL) 
              ---     +       SUM(NULL,NULL) + MAX(NULL,NULL)  

              ---     =        7*2   +   1*1   +   0 

              ---     =   15
```

Perhaps, instead of the `SUM(SupportHours) * MAX(CostPerHour)` you have, you wanted:

```
SUM(SupportHours * CostPerHour)
```

You probably also want to use:

```
SUM(MilesTraveled * CostPer_Mile)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your input. You suggestions made me re-worked the expression and got this working! Thanks a million!